# Set up Conda environment with activate script in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm

I have a Conda environment which runs an activate script in addition to setting the contained Python executable as the main interpreter. I would like to replicate this behavior in PyCharm and I'm thinking the best way to do so is by creating a customized configuration. However I am not sure where the activate script needs to go such that the environment variables are defined properly once the configuration is set. I tried the following:

[image]

As you can see I am creating a new configuration and setting the activate script path-and-filename in the Script field in the configuration options window. Unfortunately this does not work, because when I try to run the configuration I get the following error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env\python.exe C:/ProgramData/Anaconda2/envs/wps_env/etc/conda/activate.d/gdal_activate.bat
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\envs\wps_env\python.exe: can't open file 'C:/ProgramData/Anaconda2/envs/wps_env/etc/conda/activate.d/gdal_activate.bat': [Errno 2] No such file or directory
```

I know the batch script is there, however and that my location is correct.

- How can I set an activate batch script to a general configuration?
- How do I then run scripts of my choice within this configuration?

Comment: Python run configuration is for Python scripts only, it can't execute batch scripts. I don't think there's a way to do it explicitly. It should work from the box, and if it fails then it's a bug.

Comment: Its not a bug, many anaconda packages actually run activate scripts prior to entering the python session. These activate scripts define environment variables and other items necessary for the correct functioning of the package. If you use anaconda, navigate to Anaconda2/etc/conda/activate.d folder. There you may have many batch scripts which are necessary for correct functionality of each package... I need to know how to get pycharm to also run these activate scripts for a particular build configuration

Comment: I meant the bug is in PyCharms' support.